# Is my implementation of fixed-point arithmetic correct?

Tags: c++, fixed-point

A little while ago, I created a bunch of C macros for fixed-point values manipulation. Encouraged by several questions and answers on SO, I was hoping to get performance gains in a calculation-intensive part of my program. While the code seems to produce correct results, I'm wondering if it's not too naive/oversimplified, because it actually runs slower for me than regular floating-point versions of my routines (I'm doing bicubic image interpolation on Wintel). Could you please look at this short piece of code containing my macros and suggest some improvements, particularly with regard to performance? Thanks.

```
// these are architecture-dependent
typedef short int fixed16;
typedef int fixed32;
typedef __int64 fixed64;

// value of 2^n
#define POW2(n) (1 << n)

// create 16bit integer-based fixed point value from a floating point value, n is the number of bits reserved for the fractional part
#define FP_MAKE16(x, n) ((x) > 0.0 ? static_cast<fixed16>(floor((x) * POW2(n) + 0.5)) : static_cast<fixed16>(ceil((x) * POW2(n) - 0.5)))
// the same, 32bit
#define FP_MAKE32(x, n) ((x) > 0.0 ? static_cast<fixed32>(floor((x) * POW2(n) + 0.5)) : static_cast<fixed32>(ceil((x) * POW2(n) - 0.5)))
// and 64bit
#define FP_MAKE64(x, n) ((x) > 0.0 ? static_cast<fixed64>(floor((x) * POW2(n) + 0.5)) : static_cast<fixed64>(ceil((x) * POW2(n) - 0.5)))

// convert a fixed-point integer from one (n) format to another (m) assuming n < m
#define FP_CONVERT_UP(x, n, m) ((x) << (m-n))
// same for n > m
#define FP_CONVERT_DOWN(x, n, m) ((x) >> (n-m))

// convert floating-point value back to float
#define FP_FLOAT(x, n) (static_cast<float>(x) / POW2(n))
// same for double 
#define FP_DOUBLE(x, n) (static_cast<double>(x) / POW2(n))
// and for int. fractional part will be discarded! 
#define FP_INT(x, n) ((x) >> n)

// arithmetic operations for same-format numbers 
#define FP_NEG(a) ((~a)+1)
#define FP_ADD(a, b) ((a) + (b))
#define FP_SUB(a, b) ((a) + FP_NEG(b))
#define FP_MUL(a, b, n) (((a) * (b)) >> n)
#define FP_DIV(a, b, n) (((a) << n) / (b))
#define FP_POW2(a, n) (((a) * (a)) >> n)
#define FP_POW3(a, n) (((((a) * (a)) >> n)*(a)) >> n)

// arithmetic for different-format numbers, assuming n is the target (result) format and n > m
#define FP_ADD_UP(a, b, n, m) ((a) + ((b) << (n-m)))
#define FP_SUB_UP(a, b, n, m) ((a) + FP_NEG((b) << (n-m)))
#define FP_MUL_UP(a, b, n, m) (((a) * (b)) >> m)
#define FP_DIV_UP(a, b, n, m) (((a) << m) / (b))

// same for n < m
#define FP_ADD_DOWN(a, b, n, m) ((a) + ((b) >> (m-n)))
#define FP_SUB_DOWN(a, b, n, m) ((a) + FP_NEG((b) >> (m-n)))
#define FP_MUL_DOWN(a, b, n, m) (((a) * (b)) >> m)
#define FP_DIV_DOWN(a, b, n, m) (((a) << m) / (b))
```

**EDIT:** Basically, the answers and comments turned towards these two points:

- **The code is hideous, difficult to use and maintain:** I wholehartedly agree and will take the time to encapsulate it inside a class. I had some concerns about performance which were adressed and I have been convinced they were unfounded and I went to all the trouble for nothing. :)
- **Fixed-point is not worth the trouble anyway:** While that may be true on my platform, I was creating this to improve the execution speed of my code on a platform where there was no floating-point hardware. There, the floating point operations took too long and fixed was the way to go. I was only testing this on Intel because I have no access to the target hardware at the moment

While I am extremely grateful for the insight provided thus far, I was hoping to hear from somebody who actually did some calculations in fixed-point to tell me if these arithmetic operations are indeed the way to go. Perhaps there is some additional spiffy bit-twiddling that I am unaware of, that makes a difference in regard to performance or precision? In other words, if I am to encapsulate this code, can I keep the same arithmetic instructions in the inline operator functions basically the same as they are now, or should I change them somehow?

Comment: Removed `C` tag, as this is not `C` code.

Comment: The code written to use these macros is going to be brutal. Why would you *want* to do this? Honestly if I ever saw `#define FP_ADD(a, b) ((a) + (b))` in code I was forced to maintain, I would be deeply concerned.

Comment: I was figuring I'd avoid some overhead if I rejected the whole OO stuff. I could wrap the whole stuff in a class and overload arithmetic operators, but since AFAIK they are actually implemented as functions which have call overhead, I was hoping to gain some performance from doing it this way. A little obsession I'm having these days. Also, I thought maybe the compiler would have an easier time optimizing this.

Comment: @neuviemeporte: Classes without type hierarchy is not OO and they are equal to structs in C in terms of overhead introduced.

Comment: @neuviemeporte: That's a complete fallacy. The compiler will inline small functions like this. Just because `C` compilers were moronic about functions doesn't mean that `C++` compilers are. A class with arithmetic operators will not have any more overhead, at all, on a reasonable modern compiler. And it will be a gazillion times more safe and correct.

Comment: @junjanes: Are you sure? Could you point me to some docs to back that up? Also, even if that's the case - I'm guessing struct members also have to be referenced by some sort of pointer; you can't escape from "this". And pointer dereferencing also costs, doesn't it? I know this is silly, but we are talking micro-optimizations here.

Comment: @neuviemeporte: So do local variables- they are referenced from the stack pointer. You're missing the point- the compiler will remove all of this from the end result. The actual assembly will look like you generated it with a macro.

Comment: @DeadMG: I didn't realize that, it clarified a lot for me. Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

Inline functions. Use them. Not macros. Use a class, overload it's operators. And `static_cast` does not exist in C. This code is so abysmally terrible, if you posted a code sample using it, it would be totally unreadable.

Remember that floating point operations are implemented in hardware, and the fixed-point operations you've implemented are in software. There's going to be a penalty for that change and it could easily be that your code simply isn't fast enough at the algorithmic level to overcome that change.

Comment: I actually wrote the code to use this so I know you are right, and I'm practically convinced to wrap this inside a class for the sake of readability and maintainability. Still some doubts on the performance though, but I guess I'll just have to measure if there's any further hit. I just don't get what you mean by the hardware/software dichotomy. Surely the hardware performs integer operations as well. And I figure it takes more time for the CPU to multiply two floats than to multiply two ints and shift the result?

Comment: @neuviwmeporte: A float multiplication is one hardware op. int-int multiplication and then int-shift is more registers (three operands, not two) and you're invoking the hardware twice. If int-int mul is faster than float-float mul, it's worthless in many cases because you're waiting on extra memory or the time is wasted while the CPU waits for the next cycle to perform the next operation. You're also blowing more instruction cache as well. Never ever "figure" anything, *profile* it and prove your assumptions before writing code based on them.

Answer (score 4):

This is a response to @ neuviemeporte 's comments about performance. I'm making this an answer instead of comment so I can format the code more easily.

You said, "AFAIK they are actually implemented as functions which have call overhead", and "I'm guessing struct members also have to be referenced by some sort of pointer; you can't escape from 'this'". Both of those concerns are valid on their face, but let's investigate further.

I am using gcc on Linux/x86. Consider this program:

```
typedef int fixed32;
#define FP_ADD(a,b) ((a)+(b))
#define FP_NEG(a) ((~a)+1)
#define FP_SUB(a,b) ((a)+FP_NEG(b))
#define FP_INT(x,n) ((x)>>n)
#define FP_MUL(a,b,n) (((a)*(b))>>n)
#define FP_DIV(a,b,n) (((a)<<n)/(b))

template<class T, unsigned n>
struct Fixed {
private:
    T theBits;

public:
    Fixed(T t = T()) : theBits(t) {}

    Fixed operator+(const Fixed& rhs) const {
        return Fixed(theBits + rhs.theBits);
    }

    Fixed operator-(const Fixed& rhs) const {
        return Fixed(theBits - rhs.theBits);
    }

    Fixed operator~() const {
        return Fixed(~theBits);
    }

    Fixed operator*(const Fixed& rhs) const {
        return Fixed((theBits*rhs.theBits)>>n);
    }

    Fixed operator/(const Fixed& rhs) const {
        return Fixed((theBits<<n)/rhs.theBits);
    }

    operator T() const {
        return theBits >> n;
    }
};

int DoFpAdd(const fixed32 a, const fixed32 b) {
     fixed32 result = FP_ADD(a, b);
     return FP_INT(result, 16);
}

int DoFixedAdd(const Fixed<int, 16> a, const Fixed<int, 16> b) {
    return a+b;
}


int DoFpSub(const fixed32 a, const fixed32 b) {
     fixed32 result = FP_SUB(a, b);
     return FP_INT(result, 16);
}

int DoFixedSub(const Fixed<int, 16> a, const Fixed<int, 16> b) {
    return a-b;
}

int DoFpMul(const fixed32 a, const fixed32 b) {
     fixed32 result = FP_MUL(a, b, 16);
     return FP_INT(result, 16);
}

int DoFixedMul(const Fixed<int, 16> a, const Fixed<int, 16> b) {
    return a*b;
}

int DoFpDiv(const fixed32 a, const fixed32 b) {
     fixed32 result = FP_DIV(a, b, 16);
     return FP_INT(result, 16);
}
int DoFixedDiv(const Fixed<int, 16> a, const Fixed<int, 16> b) {
    return a/b;
}
```

I compiled it with this command line `g++ -O4 -Wall -pedantic -ansi -S x.cc  && c++filt <x.s > x.S`.

It may surprise you to know that the similarly-named functions produced identical assembly language. Yes, FP_ADD() and Fixed<>::operator+ are the same. No function calls (it is all inlined) no `this` pointer, just instruction-for-instruction identical assembly language.

There is no difference in execution speed. There is a huge difference in usability, maintainability and readability. I recommend that you perform a similar experiment on whatever platform you are using, and switch to a class interface.

Comment: Thanks for taking the trouble and providing this insight before I could. :)

Answer (score 2):

You can find out by writing a [unit test](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unit_tests) for your implementation. A simple realization can be achieved with successive assertations:

```
assert(FP_ADD(7, 5) == 12)
assert(FP_SUB(7, 5) == 2)
```

etc.

Cover enough use cases until you are confident with your code. Also, don't forget to compare `double`s and `float`s within a small epsilon. Equality may not work as expected due to their bit representation limitations.

Comment: I did basically just that and I am convinced it gives correct results. I just wonder if it's as fast as it can be.

Answer (score 2):

You should probably read this paper from the C++ committee - "Technical Report on C++ Performance".

http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/TR18015.pdf

It effectively kills some of the myths.